# AVSpeechSynthesizer won't work on my device

Tags: ios10, avspeechsynthesizer

AVSpeechSynthesizer won't work on my device, but it works fine on simulator. I am using Xcode 8, my phone is running iOS 10. Here is the error message I got:

> 2016-10-03 16:18:57.968375 KindmindTalk[1577:370659] Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}

Comment: Show. Your. Code.

Comment: Probably same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842363/avspeechsynthesizer-errors-in-ios-10